# iSCSI logout Input output error

Tags: linux, iscsi

203 hava a iSCSI target named poolA that I am trying to log into using this command:

```
iscsiadm -m node -T poolA -p 192.168.0.203 -l
```

I am trying to use it as a vg. Secondly, I create two lvs on this vg, and lastly, I logout:

```
iscsiadm -m node -T poolA -p 192.168.0.203 -u
```

After I execute lvs, the following error occurs:

```
/dev/dm-2: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/dm-5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
```

Can I get around this error without a reboot? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to remove the devices that no longer exist with

```
  dmsetup remove /dev/dm-2 
  dmsetup remove /dev/dm-5
```